# CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, core-text

I use core text to draw sth and it receives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problem in case of

```
CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)immutableContent);
```

I also print `immutableContent` which is a `NSAttributedString`:
[image]

The problem here is when this happens, I don't know how to debug it.
I guess there is sth wrong with the `NSAttributedString`, but I don't know how to fix it. Besides, the method used to create the `NSAttributedString` works in another project. So why I am confused~~

thanks!

Comment: are you retained object?

Comment: retain the AttributedString? I tried and the problem occurs

Comment: It is fixed in another question
[memory-management-for-ctrundelegateref-iphone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558513/memory-management-for-ctrundelegateref-iphone

Comment: Look at the same question:

[question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516871/ctframesettercreatewithattributedstring-exc-bad-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code and works fine

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStrWithLinks = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrStrWithLinks);
```

self.attributedText - NSAttributedString

Comment: thanks. You're right the method is the API from the document which should be right. I guess the string has problems but I don't know where it lies as the creation method of the string works in another project.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, what happens is that another thread is changing the attributes on the string during the framesetting.  One approach is SAKrisT's, which is to work on a copy.  Another is to serialize access to the string `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString` call.